# Mapping a component with a collection of value objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, collections, value-objects

How do I map (using xml-based approach) a `value object (component)` which contains `ISet<String>` property?

```
[Serializable]
public class Contact
{
    public ISet<String> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }       
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues).

```
<set name="PhoneNumbers" table="phone_numbers">
    <key column="contact_id">
    <element column="phone_number" type="String"/>
</set>
```

If you're going to use PhoneNumbers property just for displaying purpose, consider ["cheaper" approach with serializing the data](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2011/12/collections-of-components-alternative.html), without separate table and separate query to fetch the collection.